# Increment variable by 1 and save to db with button_to in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

Simple rails question (new to the community) and am having some trouble getting the following to work properly. Could somebody point out what I may be doing incorrectly?

I have a model called `option` that stores rows of options, and has a column, `vote_count`, that needs incremented by 1 every time the button below is clicked.

Here is my code:

Routes is below, here I want to use the vote route for the controller and button.

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    post '/vote', to: 'responds#vote', as: 'vote'
    resources :polls, except: %i( show new ) do
    resources :options, only: %i( create update destroy )
    resource :respond
    resource :visualization, only: %i( show )
  end

  root "polls#index"
end
```

Responds Controller

```
class RespondsController < ApplicationController

    def vote
        @option = option.find(1)
        @option.vote_count += 1
        @option.save
    end

  before_action :set_poll

    private

        def set_poll
            @poll = Poll.find(params[:poll_id])
        end

end
```

Here is the HTML

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application.css' %>
<div class='flex items-center'>
  <div class='w-full'>
    <div class='text-gray-700 text-3xl'>
      <%= option.title %>
      <div class="vote-count2">
        <%= button_to "Click To Vote!", vote_path, class: 'vote_count' %>
      </div>
            Total Vote Count: <%= option.vote_count %> |
            Option ID: <%= option.id %>

      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Everything is rendering properly, no errors, I am just unsure how to get the votes to increment and update in the db properly (sqlite).

Answer (score 0):

You need an HTML `<form>` wrapping that button to POST to your `vote` route.

See here for more details: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v6.1/form_helpers.html